# 500 Error response при подключении к cms оплату через paypal

Tags: java, paypal

Возникла задача подключить к cms оплату через paypal. Формируем покупку, отправляем на paypal, все отлично работает. Но, как только на `sandbox` оплачиваем тестовой картой или деньгами с аккаунта, пользователя возвращает на сайт.
Пробуем подтвердить оплату :

```
Map<String, String> sdkConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
sdkConfig.put("mode", Application.paypal_mode);
String accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(" Application.paypal_client_id", "Application.paypal_secret", sdkConfig).getAccessToken();
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
apiContext.setConfigurationMap(sdkConfig);

Payment payment = Payment.get(apiContext ,paymentId);

PaymentExecution paymentExecute = new PaymentExecution();
paymentExecute.setPayerId(payer_id);
payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecute);

payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecute);
```

> Response code: 500  Error response: {\"name\":\"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR\",\"message\":\"An internal service error has occurred\",\"information_link\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR\",\"debug_id\":\"9c390ee74d6d\"}

Если повторить тот же вызов с теми же параметрами получаем ошибку `400`, типа все для этих параметров подтверждено. 
Возможно это проблемы только `sandbox`,  но как тестировать... Может кто сталкивался ?

Comment: Вам выдается ссылка выдается на описание ошибки и Ваши действия пр ее повторении...  INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR внутренняя ошибка службы. повторите запрос в другое время. В случае если ошибка повторяется обратитесь в [службу технической поддержки Paypal Merchant](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support).

Comment: Paypal Merchant на вопросы простых смертны не отвечает. Как и любой другой сапорт paypal. Мы пробовали.

Comment: а что он Вам ответил? или просто игнорирует? жалоб вроде бы раньше не было.

Comment: просто игнорируют. судя по тому, что я читал проблема давняя. все решения, что я нашел, нам не помогли

Comment: попробуйте еще на [github paypal](https://github.com/paypal) написать по Вашей проблеме, в частности по проблемам с java - [сюда](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/issues)

Comment: Спасибо, написали еще вчера.